# Where clause works doesn't work on tinyint

Tags: sql, mysql

there is a problem with my MySQL query. I have a table with one of the columns "read" where the values are "1" by default and is automatically set to tinyint(1) by phpmyadmin instead of bool.

When I perform a query:

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE read = '1'
```

It gives an error.

But when I perform this query:

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE id = '77'
```

It is fine. I don't see any problem except that maybe tinyint cannot be searched that way. Can someone please help? I've travelled across google but found no answers.

Comment: You may want try to remove the 's  SELECT * FROM book WHERE read = 1

Comment: wish engine could make it a must to wrap column names with `backticks`..regardless of reserved or not.. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove the quotes

as it is tinyint you should not use quote (use them for strings or characters or dates)

```
select * from `table_name` where `read`=1;
```

if it doesn't work then you can do casting as mentioned by Ilion ( it's good )

Comment: Actually this is what I did and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

`READ` is a reserved word. it must be escape with backtick,

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE `read` = 1
```

- [MySQL Reserved Word Lists](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

**UPDATE 1**

Another alternative is to supply `ALIAS`, eg

```
SELECT * FROM book a WHERE a.read = 1
```

Comment: see my updated answer. you can get rid of the backticks by adding column alias.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use [**MySQL Reserved Words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) directly as a column name. **READ** is MySQL Reserved Word, if you still want to use **READ** as column name than you have use **` (backtick)** sign before and after column name.

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE `read` = 1;
```